# I keep running into a segmentation error that I can't seem to be able to fix

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, cs50, argv, argc

For a course I'm taking I'm supposed to create a program that creates a simple ciphertext from plaintext using a key that the user inputs as a command line argument.

Here's the code, it's written in C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc , string argv[])
{
    string key = argv[1];
    char keyL[2][26];
    char keyU[2][26];
    int normL = 97;
    int normU = 65;
    for (int i = 0;i <= 25;i++ , normL++, normU++)
    {
        keyL[0][i] = tolower(key[i]);
        keyU[0][i] = toupper(key[i]);
        keyL[1][i] = (char) normL;
        keyU[1][i] = (char) normU;
    }
    string plaint = get_string("plaintext:);
    string ciphert = "";
    int lengplain = strlen(plaint);
    for (int f = 0 ; f <= lengplain ; f++)
    {
        if (isupper(plaint[f]) == true)
        {
            for (int d = 0;d<=25;d++)
            {
                if (plaint[f] == keyU[0][d])
                {
                    ciphert[f] = keyL[1][d];
                }
            }
        }
        else if (islower(plaint[f]) == true)
        {
            for (int x = 0;x<=25;x++)
            {
                if (plaint[f] == keyU[0][x])
                {
                    ciphert[f] = keyL[1][x];
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ciphert[f] = plaint [f];
        }
    }
    printf("ciphertext: %s\n" , ciphert);
}
```

This compiles but I run into a segmentation error when I run it. If you spot any logical errors please keep them to yourself. It's the segmentation error I am prioritizing to fix first.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you run the program in your debugger?

Comment: Yes I did, it kept giving me the segmentation error there as well.

Comment: Try compiling with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

Comment: can you check `get_string("plaintext:);` ? a `"` is missing

Comment: I usually hit the segmentation error after the plaintext prompt so I'd assume it's all good before it.

Comment: In `ciphert[f] = keyL[1][x]` the `f` is dependent on `lengplain` yet `string ciphert = "";` can't be indexed as it is a string length `0`. Also, CS50 `string` type is hiding the fact that `ciphert` is pointing to a *string literal*, which cannot be written to, even if it has enough length.

Comment: @KoshRai The debugger has tools to help you find the problem yourself. For example, a very good start would be knowing which line causes the segmentation fault. Which the debugger will tell you.

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding:  1) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: Aside about magic numbers. a) The code uses both `25` and `26` which both relate to the *same* array length. Define a constant value *once* in the code and work from that. b) Hard coded `97` and `65` would be more readable and less error-prone as `'a'` and `'A'`.

Comment: regarding: `string ciphert = "";`   This results in a `char *` to a literal in readonly memory where that literal only contains a `'\0'`.   What is needed is an array of char (on the stack or in dynamic memory) .  Using the C VLA (varaible length array) feature, suggest: `size_t lengplain = strlen(plaint);  string ciphert[ lengplain+` ];` which results in an array, on the stack, that is long enough for the array + the NUL terminator byte.  Note: function: `strlen()` returns a `size_t`, not an `int`

Comment: OT: regarding: `string key = argv[1];`  Never access beyond `argv[0]` without first checking `argc` to assure the user actually entered the expected number of command line parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings in c are not like strings in other languages. In c, strings are pointers to an array of characters in which the last character is the null terminator `'\0'`. When you declare the string `ciphert = "";` you're essentially creating an length 1 array of characters with only the null terminator. The seg fault occurs when you try to access elements of ciphert that don't exist `ciphert[f] = plaint[f]`

You'll have to declare ciphert as an array of length `lengplain + 1` which makes it the same length as plaintext (plus the null terminator) and will allow you to do `ciphert[f] = plaint[f]`.
I recommend you take a look at some guides on strings in c.

Comment: I can't believe how much brain-damage it causes new C programmers in CS50 to use this nonsense fake `string` type

Comment: @SteveFriedl, this is the way how CS50 teaches. String is a kind of abstraction in CS50 content (within C language) to keep the stuff simple&easy in the beginning. This provides instructor to focus on other fundamental things. But in the upcoming lessons ( in "Memory Lecture"), string is explained as a pointer to the char. If you talk about pointers in the first lecture of C language, you may blow the minds away.. :)

Answer (score 2):

> string ciphert = "";

This will initialize the string with "". The problem? It is in a read-only section. And you write in this line: `ciphert[f] = plaint [f];` to this array==> You write to a readonly section==>Crash.
(Furthermore you should check argc for the number of args supplied, otherwise it will crash already in this line (`keyL[0][i] = tolower(key[i]);`)

Answer (score 0):

there are several problems with the posted code.  Here is a typical problem:

```
string plaint = get_string("plaintext:);
```

The parameter to `get_string()` has to be a pointer to a NUL terminated character array.

This parameter:

```
"plaintext:
```

is missing the trailing double quote: `"`

Have you ever tried to compile the posted code?  I think not, because the compile would have failed due to this problem.

When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.

for `gcc` suggest:

```
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11
```

Note that other compilers use different options to produce the same results.

regarding;

```
int lengplain = strlen(plaint);
```

The function: `strlen()` returns a `size_t`, not an `int`

regarding;

```
string key = argv[1];
```

Never access beyond `argv[0]` without first checking `argc` to assure the expected command line parameter was actually entered by the user.

regarding:

```
int normL = 97;
int normU = 65;
```

it is a poor programming practice to use 'magic' numbers as they make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest;

```
int normL = 'a';
int normU = 'A';
```

regarding:

```
char keyL[2][26];
char keyU[2][26];
```

the 'magic' number `26` is meaningless.  Suggest (after the `#include` statements) define a meaningful name:

```
#define alphabetLen 26
```

Then use that meaningful name throughout the code.

You could save the readers of your code a lot of aggravation by changing:

```
for (int i = 0;i <= 25;i++ , normL++, normU++)
{
    keyL[1][i] = (char) normL;
    keyU[1][i] = (char) normU;
```

to

```
for ( int i = 0; i < alphabetLen; i++ )   
{
    keyL[1][i] =  normL + 'a';
    keyU[1][i] =  normU + 'A';
```

And:

```
int normL = 97;
int normU = 65;
```

to:

```
int normL = 'a';
int normU = 'A';
```

Of course, to eliminate a couple of the warnings, this

```
keyL[1][i] = normL;
keyU[1][i] = normU;
```

would be better written (and no compiler warnings) via:

```
keyL[1][i] = (char) normL;
keyU[1][i] = (char) normU;
```

regarding;

```
string ciphert = "";
```

This produces a pointer into readonly memory to a literal that is only 1 char long.   Since it is in readonly memory, the code cannot write to it, nor offsets from it.  Suggest:

```
string ciphert[ 26+1 ];
```